# php string replace function

Tags: php, sql, string

I need to write a function that takes in a long string that is a sql command and searches for an equal sign goes back to the word before it and adds "post." before it.

Example:

input:

```
$sqlFilter = "WHERE sport = 'Hockey' AND team = 'New York Rangers';
```

Output:

```
$sqlFilter = "WHERE post.sport = 'Hockey' AND post.team = 'New York Rangers';
```

Comment: just looking for some sudo code on where to start.. I can scan the whole string with for loops find the equal character and then go back and replace using the spaces as markers but there might and probably is a better way

Comment: A regex pattern may work... probably not going to be battle proof though. https://regex101.com/r/rK1qP5/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write any function because you have a `preg_replace`.

You need to add this code

```
$newSqlFilter = preg_replace('/([^(\s]*?)[ ]{0,}=/', 'post.\0', $sqlFilter);
```

And the other thing - close your query string with `"` character.

Comment: ^ see this is why I asked.. my php knowledge is basically limited to C knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: .. I am not so great with regex and actually have a bracket at the start and end of the filter variable so getting an error like "WHERE post.(sport = 'Hockey' AND post.team = 'New York Rangers') work around to get it on the inside of the bracket?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression search pattern, using function preg_replace_callback(), that accepts callback method name to make replacement. You use expression to find desired pattern and use callback method to make replacement.

Read more about here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php